# issue in accessing javascript object on looping

Tags: javascript, loops, object

In `for..in` loop,

Why does the value of a property when accessed as `o.i` returns `undefined` however `o[i]` returns the correct value?

Code snippet for reference:

```
var object = {
   id:2,
   name:'axs',
   address:'colon street'
};

for(let property in object){
  console.log(object.property); // returns undefined
  console.log(object[property]); // returns property-value
}
```

Comment: What exactly you wants to do? Can you please elaborate it more?

Answer (score 4):

`o.i` will look for property `i` in the `Object` but when you do `o[i]` it looks for the evaluated property `i` which may be: `name`, `id`, etc...

While fetching properties with a `dot` notation, the variable is not evaluated, it is considered that you are trying to fetch the property `i` itself.

Answer (score 1):

In `for..in` loop, `property` is assigned to the variable as a *string* i.e inside the loop, `typeof(i)` will always return `"string"`. [MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on how `for..in` works.

When accessed with the dot notation, engine tries to read as `o."name"`, which it correctly finds as `undefined`. Please note `o.name` and `o."name"` are 2 different things.

Accessing object's properties using

- [the dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) - `property` must be a valid JavaScript identifier i.e. `property` will get evaluated to return the required value.
- [the bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) - `property` is *always* a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier, it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

PS

When accessing object properties with `for..in`, Please note if you want to consider properties attached to the object only, and not its prototypes. In such a case use `getOwnPropertyNames()` or perform a `hasOwnProperty()` check. [MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only)

Answer (score 0):

They are different ways of accessing object properties. o.i is equivalent to o['i'], which in your case is not present,  so undefined is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `object.property` returns undefined, because no property named `property` is found on `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the dot notation sees `property` as a property of the object used. To use the 'property' from the `for-in` loop as a variable, you need to use the square bracket accessors.

If you give your object a 'property' property, it works as expected:

```js
var object = {
   id:2,
   name:'axs',
   address:'colon street',
   property:'residential'
};

for(let property in object){
  console.log(object.property); // returns 'residential'
  console.log(object[property]); // returns property-value
}
```